# Пожалуйста объясните в чём разница

Tags: c#

Пожалуйста объясните в чём разница

Если пишу такой код:

```
class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {

    string str = "Hello Bro";
    
    string[] vowels = new string[] { "A", "a", "E", "e", "I", "i", "O", "o", "U", "u" }; 
   
    for (int i = 0; i < vowels.Length; i++) {

      str = str.Replace(vowels[i], "");
      
    }
    Console.WriteLine(str);
  }
}
```

Вывод в консоль: Hll Br

По сути то что и требовалось, но если пишу такой код:

```
class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {

    string str = "Hello Bro";
    
    string[] vowels = new string[] { "A", "a", "E", "e", "I", "i", "O", "o", "U", "u" }; 

    string result = "";
   
    for (int i = 0; i < vowels.Length; i++) {

      result = str.Replace(vowels[i], "");
      
    }
    Console.WriteLine(result);
  }
}
```

То вывод в консоль следующий: Hello Bro

Это уже не то что требовалось, и собственно вопрос в следующем, почему если я завожу новую переменную и присваиваю туда решение то у меня один вывод, а если я присваиваю решение в старую переменную, то у меня другой вывод?

Comment: Чтобы изменения накапливались, надо писать `result = result.Replace(...)`

Comment: `string result = str`, `result = result.Replace`

Answer (score 4):

Потому что метод `Replace` не меняет значение в исходной строке, а только возвращает новую.
Таким образом на последней итерации цикла вы в `result` кладете оригинальную строку `str` из которой убрана строка `u`.

Answer (score 2):

> Как-то все скупы на разъяснения, однако...

Метод [Replace(char oldChar, char newChar](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8) возвращает новую строку, в которой значения oldChar заменены на newChar/ Из документации:
`Returns a new string in which all occurrences of a specified Unicode character in this instance are replaced with another specified Unicode character.`

В той же документации отдельным пояснением указано:
`This method does not modify the value of the current instance. Instead, it returns a new string in which all occurrences of oldChar are replaced by newChar.`

То есть метод этот саму строку НЕ изменяет, а просто возвращает новую, в которой все вхождения oldChar заменены на newChar...

В вашем коде в цикле в переменную result будут поочередно записываться значения:

```
Hello Bro - без A
Hello Bro - без a
Hello Bro - без E
Hllo Bro - без e
Hello Bro - без I
Hello Bro - без i
Hello Bro - без O
Hell Br - без o
Hello Bro - без U
Hello Bro - без U
```

Так как изначальная строка str будет оставаться одинаковой, то эти гласные буквы будут удаляться каждут итерацию из **изначальной** строки `Hello Bro`

Comment: @Ziwerty Если мой ответ был вам полезен, пожалуйста, примите его, нажав галочку. Это будет значить, что ответ был получен, вопрос - решен.